# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Stocks"

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to edit the whole form by using the updateOne function of mongoose but whenever I clicks the edit button, it shows error **CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Stocks".**

**counter.js**

```
const counterSchema = {
    id: {
        type: String
    },
    
    seq: {
        type: Number
    }
}
```

**stocks.js**

```
const stockSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number
    },
    flowerName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
    },{timestamps: true }
);
```

This is from my post Method wherein I add a value to the form

```
Counter.findOneAndUpdate(
        {id: "autoval"}, 
        {"$inc":{"seq": 1}}, 
        {new: true}, (err, cd) => {


            let seqID;
            if(cd==null) {
                const newValue = new Counter({id: "autoval", seq:1})
                newValue.save() 
                seqID = 1
            } else { 
                seqID = cd.seq
            }

            const qty = Number(req.body.quantity)
            const price = Number(req.body.pricePieces)
           
            const stock = new Stocks ({
                id: seqID,
                flowerName: req.body.flowerName
            })
            stock.save()
                .then(result => {
                    res.redirect('flowers-in-stock');
                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    )
```

And I want to proceed in the edit page

```
   Stocks.findById(req.params.id)
        .then (stock => {
            res.render('flowers-in-stock-edit', {stocks: stock})
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [findById](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findById) function matches its parameter with the `_id` field in the document in MongoDB.

Your schema defines `id` but not `_id`, so the `_id` will be automatically created on insert, and will be type ObjectId.

`findById` attempts to cast its parameter to match the datatype of the `_id` field.  The error message indicates that you are passing `"1"` as the value to find, which `findById` is attempting to cast to ObjectId.  `"1"` is not a valid ObjectId, so that fails.

To search based on your `id` field, use [findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findOne) instead of `findById`:

```
Stocks.findOne({id: req.params.id})
```